# changing name of website title when click Facebook like

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I created a web app with Rails and gave it the name on my local host LP4. Rails then made that the title of the site and, without thinking, I forgot to change it once I added a Facebook like button. Now anytime I or anyone else clicks "like" it shows that they like "LP4" on their facebook page.   The only place it said LP4 on my site was in the title tags and I've changed them to the proper title of the site.

Furthermore, I put the Facebook meta tags in the header of my site indicating the new title etc, and the like button still puts "LP4" on the Facebook page.

I also never put the title LP4 on Facebook's developer settings http://developers.facebook.com  so I don't know where it's getting it from.

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My New Title"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://mydomain.com/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://blah.png"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="2484848484848"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="random site description."/
```

>

[image]

Comment: You need to request a Facebook scrape. Try this solution: 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975498/submitting-object-to-facebook-via-open-graph-doesnt-work-but-then-works-after][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975498/submitting-object-to-facebook-via-open-graph-doesnt-work-but-then-works-after