# FB Open Graph OAuthException: (#3502) og:type is website and not namespace:object

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to add a custom action and object to my website with og. As stated in previous questions I searched through, the debugger scrapes the website properly and confirms that it is they way it should be without any errors, warnings, or exceptions.

However, when I post to that object with the php sdk, I am getting this exception from FB:

> OAuthException: (#3502) Object at URL //mypage.com/image/details has og:type of 'website'. The property 'photo' requires an object of og:type 'app_prod:photo'.

[note I have removed all "http://" so that stackoverflow would not render them as links]

The php sdk call:

> $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/app_prod:love', 'POST', array(
>             'photo' => '//mypage.com/image/details',
>             'access_token' => $token
>           ));

The head of the page looks like this:

> <head prefix="og: //ogp.me/ns# fb: //ogp.me/ns/fb# app_prod: //ogp.me/ns/fb/app_prod#">
>
> <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID">
>   <meta property="og:type" content="app_prod:photo">
>   <meta property="og:url" content="http://mypage.com/image/details">
>   <meta property="og:title" content="A Picture I love">
>   <meta property="og:image" content="http://images.mypage.com/8f9117301e00dbfb.jpg">
>   <meta property="og:description" content="Here is a description">

Things I've double checked:

1. I have the correct app id.
2. When I use the curl command supplied by facebook for the action, it posts fine.
3. My head and meta tags are exactly what I copied from the object "code" that facebook supplies.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JeffSherlock This would be an example of the url of the page that contains a photo that someone would love http://stage.lover.ly/image/78528

Comment: So I believe that the real solution here is to remember that when testing with localhost, facebook cannot scrape the page, so it defaults to og:type of website - hence why I was seeing this on my local project.

As for why it is happening on my staging server, I am still looking into that.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? Is it a caching issue at Facebook? I'm have the same issue and haven't solved yet.

Comment: Somehow facebook posted an article about this 'bug' but as you say, we already do it like in this article and the bug still occurs: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/612/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](http://alvinwoon.com/blog/?p=267) and on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975498/submitting-object-to-facebook-via-open-graph-doesnt-work-but-then-works-after).

> The problem is usually caused by a server race condition – the
>   application’s inability to handle two simultaneous HTTP requests.
>   Sometimes when a user performs an action and the application calls a
>   FB open graph request right away, chances are the new object page
>   hasn’t been generated yet.

```
var openGraphUrl = '/me/' + OG_NAMESPACE + ':' + OG_ACTION + '?' + OG_OBJECT + '=' + siteURL;
var scrapeUrl    = '/?ids='+siteURL+'&scrape=true';
_.setTimeout(function(){
  FB.api(scrapeUrl, 'post',
    function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log('scrap: '+response.error.message);
      } else {
        FB.api(openGraphUrl, 'post',
          function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
          console.log('OG: '+response.error.message);
        } else {
          console.log('Successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    });
}
, 5000);
```