# Like button on content will not work until URL is submitted to Facebook debug tool

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-7, facebook-like, pantheon

I'm troubleshooting an issue where the Like button won't work on my site unless the URL is submitted to the [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

When I hit like I'm seeing two requests fire to comment_widget_shell.php. Once succeeds (302 found), while the other fails, showing a status "(canceled)" and type "pending":

The successful request:

```
Request URL:http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_widget_shell.php?locale=en_US&master_frame_name=f236db264&offsetX=0&sdk=joey
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
```

The failed request:

```
Request URL:https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_widget_shell.php?locale=en_US&master_frame_name=f236db264&offsetX=0&sdk=joey
```

As of the writing of this question, here is an example URL where like fails:

http://www.zujava.com/geisha-makeup

I iniitally thought it was this [Stack Overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975498/submitting-object-to-facebook-via-open-graph-doesnt-work-but-then-works-after), as the site runs on a platform somewhat similar to Heroku, but for Drupal (Pantheon) and I can't reproduce the issue locally. However, I contacted Pantheon support and they reported the Heroku limitation does not exist on Pantheon.

I'm not sure what other tools I can use to debug this. My article pages get a clean report from the Facebook Debugger. Any ideas or tips of what I can look deeper into?

Answer (score 0):

I have had pretty good luck with pantheon. If your just trying to get a like button on drupal why not use http://drupal.org/project/fb_social/ I have used this in d7 and d6 and I have never had a problem.

Pantheon should be able to handle a request to facebook for sure

thanks

Nick