# Open Graph meta data won't load until after being parsed by the debugger?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I added open graph meta data to all the articles in a site, however, when I attempt to post an article link on Facebook, the meta information isn't loaded.

Then, when I insert the URL [into the debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), it works, both within the debugger and when posting regularly on Facebook.

This issue seems to have been [addressed in the past, in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975498/submitting-object-to-facebook-via-open-graph-doesnt-work-but-then-works-after). That question pertains to a rails environment where the application couldn't handle multiple http requests at the same time. The issue was solved by handling all Facebook API requests in the background.

What's the simplest fashion in which I could accomplish this in a PHP environment running Wordpress?