# Facebook is not reading OG META TAGS

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

i have problem with SHARE/LIKE or whatever on my site with facebook meta tags.

I am reading all forums and so but still didnt find answer, why when i click on share / like there is no information, no title, no image, nothing, only URL (haluze.eu).

Site: http://haluze.eu/video/vynikajuci-vykon-v-sou-svedsko-ma-talent/1082/

I have checked OG reader http://ogp.spypixel.com/ and all og tags have been successfully red. 
BUT, when i check mentioned site with FB DEBUG i got errors like: **The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.**

You can see meta tags in source code of mentioned site.

I AM LOST!!! Thanks for help.

Comment: Seems like some caching issue. Looks like it works now

Comment: thank for ansfwer :) yes something happend now, but dont know what...picture and everything showed for this site now. MIRACLE? but still nothing for this new one: http://haluze.eu/video/celeste-buckingham-v-slovenskej-rozpravke/2/ maybe if someone else watch it NOT ME it cache??? dont know how it worls...

Comment: I am having the same problem too. Weird, I hope it's temporary

Comment: yes i thoug about it there is some problem not on my side but fb or so... so i will wait, please let me know if u know more :)

Comment: hey, so apparently in my case it's not FB, it's the web server that I am using (gunicorn), read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975498/submitting-object-to-facebook-via-open-graph-doesnt-work-but-then-works-after)