# Like button using wrong page title, as well as using random jpeg below as a logo

Tags: facebook-likebox

I just added a Facebook activity feed, and Like buttons on a web page I am designing for another business (seen here- thespotinvernal.com).  It appears that when people "like" the page it brings up the former title of the page (raveninkdesign-home) from when I was designing the page under my domain, as well as trying to display the jpeg sitting below the like button as some sort of logo.  I have tried creating new code figuring the title it was picking up was some sort of algorithm based creation from when I placed the first code for the feed.  But getting new script, and new html did nothing to change that.  Anyone know how I can fix these two strange problems?

Answer (score 1):

Check now. I think I cleared your cached data accidentally :)
Using the info given in this post [How to clear debug tool cache data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237980/how-to-clear-debug-tool-cache-data)

From the post:

> ```
> Go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
> Enter the URL following by fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING
> ```

Put

```
thespotinvernal.com?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING
```

inside "Input URL or Access Token" text box and click DEBUG button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just accessing a cached copy? Facebook doesn't want to have to fetch the liked page on every like. Instead, it fetches it the first time, then keeps a cached copy for some time. This includes page title and images.

So let me guess, the first time you tried the "like" was with the previous contents? Then you probably just need to give it some time to expire from Facebook caches.

Comment: okay ill try that and hope in a few days it fixes itself.  Thanks for the help.  I didn't think about the fact my page needs scraped since changing domains so you're probably right.