# Facebook/messenger's inbuilt browser keeps caching page

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, facebook

I'm having a serious issue with android's inbuilt browser (I assume that's what messenger uses anyway).

The issue is that HTML content on our page is dynamic and has to be always updated per reload, however, the content itself is being cached within the browser.

Scripts, css and other types of caching have no effect, since the URLs being loaded are cached as well.

Example:

```
echo time();
```

Will output 1571044358

However, every time I re-open the link (from messenger) it will always output 1571044358, instead of actually reloading the page.

Chrome and regular browsers are obviously working fine, it's just the inbuilt browser that's causing the issue.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I think it is about cache strategy of Facebook rather than browser cache. You can try [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) tool to clear cache and check if it would work.

Comment: You can have a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237980/how-to-clear-debug-tool-cache-data)

Comment: I can not force users to uniquely update the URL when they share it, I assume that's what the second link is hinting at

Comment: Yes exactly. You can append a unique query parameter (such as timestamp) to force FB to re-fetch the page

Comment: I can't do that. If someone shares a link with unique key 123, the user that opens it will always have that query 123, it won't be unique and the page will still be cached